# Task orchestration implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having trouble in implementing an elegant functional style solution to a program that need to orchestrates different task. Here is what I want to achieve.

I have three classes whose methods I want to orchestrate (simplified for brevity):

```
class TaskA {
    public ResultA call() {
        return new ResultA();
    }
}

class TaskB {
    public ResultB call(ResultA a) {
        return new ResultB();
    }
}

class TaskC {
    public ResultC call(List<ResultB> resultBs) {
        return new ResultC();
    }
}
```

I need to execute `TaskA` 'n' times in parallel and for each execution of `TaskA`, i need to execute `TaskB` 'n' times using the result of the corresponding `TaskA`. Finally I need to execute `TaskC` once using the results of all the invocations of `TaskB`.

One way of achieving this would be to create a `Callable` that encapsulates the call to `TaskA` and `TaskB` and finally in my main thread, collect the `List` of `Future`s of `ResultB` to execute `TaskC`:

```
class TaskATaskBCallable implements Callable<ResultB> {
    private TaskA taskA ...;
    private TaskB taskB ...;

    public ResultB call() {
        return taskB.call(taskA.call());
    }
}
```

And in my main thread:

```
private ResultC orchestrate() {
    ExecutorService service = ...;
    List<Callable<ResultB>> callables = ...;

    taskC.call(callables.map(callable -> 
        service.submit(callable)).map(Future::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

One thing I don't like about this solution is the `TaskATaskBCallable`. This probably is a needless class coupling `TaskA` and `TaskB`. Moreover, if I have to chain another task to `TaskA` and `TaskB`, I will have to modify the `TaskATaskBCallable` also possibly modify its name. I feel I can get rid of it by smarter usage of the Java concurrent library classes like `CompletableFuture`'s or `Phaser`.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this using `CompletableFuture`:

```
private ResultC orchestrate() {
    ExecutorService service = ...;
    int taskCount = ...;

    List<CompletableFuture<ResultB>> resultBFutures = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, taskCount)
                    .mapToObj((i) -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new TaskA().call(), service))
                    .map(resultAFuture -> resultAFuture.thenApplyAsync(resultA -> new TaskB().call(resultA),
                                    service))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new TaskC().call(CompletableFuture.allOf(resultBFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[resultBFutures.size()]))
                    .thenApply(v -> resultBFutures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join)
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                    .join());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think indeed CompletableFuture will prove most elegant :

```
    int taskCount = 100;

    List<ResultB> resultBs = IntStream.range(0, taskCount)
            .mapToObj(i -> new TaskA())
            .map(taskA -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(taskA::call))
            .map(completableFutureA -> completableFutureA.thenApplyAsync(new TaskB()::call))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // collect, in order to kick off the async tasks
            .stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new TaskC().call(resultBs);
```

Comment: Not quite, your `CompletableFuture::join` makes the whole thing serial. Your solution executes the following graph in serial: `TaskA->TaskB->TaskA->TaskB....->TaskC`

Comment: @SwarangaSarma you're right, I need to collect prior to joining, or the lazy evaluation of the Stream screws me :)